# Image not saved Camera API 2

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera2

I'm having an issue with my camera. When the capture button is clicked the Uri is captured, but the image is not actually stored on the external storage. It seems that it is discarded or I have messed something up. This used to work properly but trying to integrate with my GreenDao database it no longer works.

```
 package com.example.joelg.lion.Camera;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.ImageFormat;
import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCharacteristics;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraMetadata;
import android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest;
import android.hardware.camera2.TotalCaptureResult;
import android.hardware.camera2.params.StreamConfigurationMap;
import android.media.Image;
import android.media.ImageReader;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Size;
import android.util.SparseIntArray;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.TextureView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.joelg.lion.Gallery.GalleryActivity;
import com.example.joelg.lion.Job.ImgStore;
import com.example.joelg.lion.Job.JobActivity;
import com.example.joelg.lion.Job.Lion;
import com.example.joelg.lion.R;
import com.example.joelg.lion.db.DaoSession;

import org.greenrobot.greendao.annotation.NotNull;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import static com.example.joelg.lion.R.id.GalleryBtn;
import static java.lang.String.*;


public class CameraActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Runnable {
    private static final String TAG = "AndroidCameraApi";
    private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();
    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 200;

    static {
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
    }

    protected CameraDevice cameraDevice;
    protected CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSessions;
    protected CaptureRequest.Builder captureRequestBuilder;
    Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    String ImgTimeStamp = currentTime.toString();
    private TextureView textureView;
    private final CameraDevice.StateCallback stateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onOpened");
            cameraDevice = camera;
            createCameraPreview();

        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice camera) {
            Log.e(TAG, "On Disconnected");
            // cameraDevice.close();
            // stopBackgroundThread();


        }

        @Override
        public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int error) {
            cameraDevice.close();
            cameraDevice = null;
        }
    };
    private ImageButton takePictureButton;
    private Size imageDimension;
    TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener textureListener = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
            openCamera();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
        }
    };
    //save file
    private File file;
    private Handler mBackgroundHandler = new Handler();
    private String cameraId;
    private int CameraWidth = 1440;
    private int CameraHeight = 2960;
    private HandlerThread mBackgroundThread;

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Thread Running");
    }

    private Long ImgID() {
        long upperLimit = 15L;
        long lowerLimit = 0L;

        Long GeneratedID = lowerLimit + ( long ) (Math.random() * upperLimit - lowerLimit);
        return GeneratedID;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
        textureView = findViewById(R.id.texture);
        assert textureView != null;
        textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);
        takePictureButton = findViewById(R.id.CaptureBtn);

        assert takePictureButton != null;

        ///##############################################

        takePictureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                takePicture();
            }
        });


        //################################################
        ImageButton BackButton = findViewById(R.id.BackCamBtn);
        BackButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(CameraActivity.this, JobActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);


                }
            }
        });



        //#######################################
         ImageButton GalleryButton = findViewById(GalleryBtn);
        GalleryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                {


                    //onPause();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(CameraActivity.this, GalleryActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            }
        });
    }


    protected void takePicture() {
        if (null == cameraDevice) {
            Log.e(TAG, "cameraDevice is null");
            return;
        }
        CameraManager manager = ( CameraManager ) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraDevice.getId());
            Size[] jpegSizes = null;
            if (characteristics != null) {
                jpegSizes = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP)
                        .getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG);
            }
            int width = CameraWidth;
            int height = CameraHeight;
            if (jpegSizes != null && 0 < jpegSizes.length) {
                width = jpegSizes[0].getWidth();
                height = jpegSizes[0].getHeight();
            }
            final ImageReader reader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, ImageFormat.JPEG, 10);

            List<Surface> outputSurface = new ArrayList<>(2);
            outputSurface.add(reader.getSurface());
            outputSurface.add(new Surface(textureView.getSurfaceTexture()));

            final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
            captureBuilder.addTarget(reader.getSurface());
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);

            //check oreintation
            int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));
            DaoSession daoSession = (( Lion ) getApplication()).getDaoSession();
            try {


                 file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        , (ImgID() +".jpg"));
                String FilePath = file.getPath();
                daoSession.insert(new ImgStore("", FilePath, ImgTimeStamp, ImgID()));
                Log.d("APP_DEBUG", "Image saved : " + file.toString());
                List<ImgStore> imgList = daoSession.loadAll(ImgStore.class);
                for (ImgStore img : imgList) {
                    Log.d("APP_DEBUG", img.getImgURL());

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //
            }



            HandlerThread handlerThread=new HandlerThread("takepicture");
            handlerThread.start();
            mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());
            ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener readerListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {


                @Override
                public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader imageReader) {
                    Image image = null;
                    try {
                        image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                        ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
                        buffer.get(bytes);
                        save(bytes);

                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        {
                            if (image != null)
                                image.close();
                        }
                    }
                }

                private void save(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
                    OutputStream outputStream = null;
                    try {

                        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        textureView.getBitmap().compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,outputStream);

                    } finally {
                        if (outputStream != null)
                            outputStream.close();


                    }
                }

            };

            reader.setOnImageAvailableListener(readerListener, mBackgroundHandler);
            final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureListener = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
                    super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
                    Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, "Saved" + file, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    createCameraPreview();

                }
            };
            cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(outputSurface, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(@NotNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    try {
                        cameraCaptureSession.capture(captureBuilder.build(), captureListener, mBackgroundHandler);
                    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(@NotNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {

                }
            }, mBackgroundHandler);

        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private void createCameraPreview() {
        try {
            SurfaceTexture texture = textureView.getSurfaceTexture();

            assert texture != null;
            texture.setDefaultBufferSize(imageDimension.getWidth(), imageDimension.getHeight());
            Surface surface = new Surface(texture);
            captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
            captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);
            cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    if (cameraDevice == null)
                        return;
                    cameraCaptureSessions = cameraCaptureSession;
                    updatePreview();
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, "Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }, null);

        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void updatePreview() {
        if (cameraDevice == null)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
        try {
            cameraCaptureSessions.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequestBuilder.build(), null, mBackgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private void openCamera() {
        CameraManager manager = ( CameraManager ) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            cameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[0];
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
            StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
            assert map != null;
            imageDimension = map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class)[0];
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                        Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                }, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
                return;
            }
            manager.openCamera(cameraId, stateCallback, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NotNull String[] permissions, @NotNull int[] grantResullts) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION) {
            if (grantResullts[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "you cant use camera without permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (textureView.isAvailable())
            openCamera();
        else
            textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();


    }

    private void closeCamera() {
        Log.e(TAG, "Closing Camera");

        if (null != cameraDevice) {
            cameraDevice.close();
            cameraDevice = null;
            stopBackgroundThread();

        }

    }


    private void stopBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundThread.quitSafely();
        try {
            mBackgroundThread.join();
            mBackgroundThread = null;
            mBackgroundThread = null;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

this may be already solved but I couldn't find a working solution.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after going back over my code it turns out my save mechanism was broken and adding this resolved the issue

```
 private File getOutputMediaFile() {
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Lion");
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d("Lion", "failed to create Dir");
            return null;
        }
    }
    timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_ " + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    TempImg = mediaFile.toString();

    return mediaFile;
}
```

when this is applied to my save function it works